# How do I create a function to change values ​in an array?

Tags: c

Write a function int set_array(int *v, int i, int j, int k) that sets the elements i to j to a specific value k among the elements of the int array v of size n (<= 100). This is the given problem.

When I input 10 0 9 -1, to set all the elements it comes out normally as -1.

However, when 5 2 2 0 is input, to set only element `[2]`, all output values ​​come out as 0.

I am using eclipse and no error came out. Which part is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int set_array(int* v, int i, int j, int k)
{
    int t;
    for (t = i; t <= j; t++)
    {
        v[t] = k;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    int size, value;
    int start, end;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &size, &start, &end, &value);

    int array[size];

    for (t = 0; t < size; t++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[t]);
    }

    set_array(array, start, end, value);

    for (t = 0; t < size; t++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[t]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: you know what `int n, i, j, k, t;` are for, but we don't. Code is easier to follow when meaningful identifier names are used.

Comment: It is not wrong. You did not explicitly set elements `[0]`, `[1]`, `[3]` and `[4]`, and they happened to be `0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay! I'll fix it

Comment: Which ones should I close?

Comment: Now that the typos are fixed, I cannot reproduce the problem. So, the close reason is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `t` and `i` as the `for` loops indexes:

```
for (t = 0; t < n; t++)
{
    scanf("%d", &ary[i]);
}
```

In this case you only scan `i` position, not the `t` running the for loop
Be careful using many one letters variables...

Comment: I guess it needs clarification

Comment: I'm not sure why it's 0. I entered 5 2 2 0 and 1 2 3 4 5 and they all changed to 0. And which ones weren't scanned?

Comment: A uninitiated array has undefined behavior (sorta), if you try and read it before any value is added it can show any value, in your case a bunch of zeroes. change your scan loop to `for (t = 0; t < n; t++){scanf("%d", &ary[t]);}
` and you'll read the t'th element on every iteration

Comment: I missed the original typo.

Answer (score 2):

The initialization of the array is incorrect.
In `scanf` and `printf` the `i` should be replaced by the letter `t`.